# AutoNumber per group box in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports

I'd like to add Auto Number per group box in crystal report. Here I use Record Number but it increases by group box.

Report View
[image: Report View]

The AutoNumber will be at the front of Barcode Column. How to set it per group box?

Comment: +1 for adding a screen shot. It makes it a lot easier to understand your report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an incremental number for each record displayed in a group you need to do use a Running Total Field.

1. Create a new Running Total Field
2. Give it a suitable name
3. The `Field to summarize` can be any field, in your case `Barcode`
4. The `Type of Summary` should be `Count`
5. In the `Evaluate` section you need to select `For each record`
6. In the `Reset` section you need to select `On Change of group` and then select the Group Name from the drop down.
7. Place this Running Total Field next to the Barcode field.

This should give you an incremental number for each record in your group.

Comment: Thank you, Barry. You also give me a simple guide.